# How do I change sprites in scripts?

Tags: godot, gdscript

I'm trying to make a dating sim as a easy first game programming-wise. I don't know how to change the character sprites inside the scripts.

character_sprite.gd

```
extends Sprite

var char_tex = load("res://Sprites/Lu2.png") 

func _ready():
    set_texture(char_tex)

func _input(event):
    if event is InputEventMouseButton:
        char_tex = load("res://Sprites/Lu1.png")
        update()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just set the `texture` property to the desired texture. You could also [preload](http://docs.godotengine.org/en/latest/classes/class_@gdscript.html?highlight=preload#class-gdscript-preload) the textures and then just switch them instead of loading them again.

```
extends Sprite

var char_tex = load("res://Sprites/Lu2.png") 

func _ready():
    set_process_input(true)
    texture = char_tex

func _input(event):
    if event is InputEventMouseButton:
        texture = load("res://Sprites/Lu1.png")
```

The problem in your example was that you only assigned a new image to the `char_tex` variable, but that doesn't change the texture of the sprite. The `texture` will still refer to the previous image until you assign the new one with `texture =` or `set_texture`. Gdscript is relatively similar to Python in this regard, so I recommend taking a look at Ned Batchelder's talk [Facts and myths about Python names and Values](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names1.html).